# Returning wcf stream from service fabric actors/services

Tags: wcf, azure-service-fabric

I am hoping this is a simple question.

I want to create a cluster of services that process dynamic reports that involve any number of several thousand fields.  From what I can tell, I can't use a stream as a return type from a reliable actor or service.  Are my only options to return serialised byte arrays or to write the results elsewhere and direct clients to query that resource instead, or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the communication stack you use in your services. Services themselves are agnostic to communication protocols. Implementations of services can plug in any communication stack: Web API, WCF, sockets, doesn't matter.

Reliable Actors is a special implementation of a service, and as a service implementation it specifies a communication stack. In that communication stack, request/response payloads have to be DataContract serializable, so no you can't return a stream there.

Otherwise, if you're using WCF to communicate with your services, then you're limited by what WCF can do.

If you're using service remoting (where your service implements IService and you use a ServiceProxy to call methods on it remotely), then no you can't return a stream for a service method. You need to return something that is DataContract serializable.

If you're using Web API in your service, you can grab the HTTP response stream in a controller action method and stream your data back without allocating a byte buffer for it.

Or you can implement your own communicaton protocol and do whatever you want.